# Result text from when creating a new user does not display

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I create a new user I want it to display if there are errors like the username already exists or password is to short etc.  So I have this code:

```
protected void CreateAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      MembershipCreateStatus p = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
      System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(Username.Text, Password.Text,
           Email.Text, passwordQuestion, SecurityAnswer.Text, true, out p);

      switch (p)
      {
           case MembershipCreateStatus.Success:
           CreateAccountResults.Text = "The user account was successfully created!";
           break;

           // other cases omitted for brevity

           default:
                CreateAccountResults.Text = 
                     "There was an unknown error; the user account was NOT created.";
           break;
      }
 }
```

It creates the user but doesn't display any error messages.  For example when i create a user with the same username as one already created and a password of 4 characters long and click on create, nothing happens the user doesn't get created and no error messages are displaying.  When I create a user that doesn't exist and a strong password with it then creates the user but doesn't display the "user was created successfully"  message

Here is the form I am using:

```
 <p>
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="InvalidUserNameOrPasswordMessage"
           Visible="false" EnableViewState="false" ForeColor="Red">
      </asp:Label>
 </p>

 Username:<br />
 <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid Username is required">
      <asp:TextBox ID="Username" runat="server" class="input100"></asp:TextBox>
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      <span class="symbol-input100">
           <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
 </div>
 <br />
 <br />

 Password:<br />
 <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid Password is required">
      <asp:TextBox ID="Password" TextMode="Password" runat="server" class="input100"></asp:TextBox>
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      <span class="symbol-input100">
           <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
 </div>
 <br />
 <br />

 Email Address:<br />
 <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid Email Address is required">
      <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" class="input100"></asp:TextBox>
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      <span class="symbol-input100">
           <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
 </div>
 <br />
 <br />

 Job Title:<br />
 <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid Job Title is required">
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="SecurityQuestion"></asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="SecurityAnswer" runat="server" class="input100"></asp:TextBox>
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      <span class="symbol-input100">
           <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
 </div>
 <br />
 <br />

 <asp:Button ID="CreateAccountButton" runat="server"
      Text="Create the User Account" 
      OnClick="CreateAccountButton_Click" 
      class="login100-form-btn" />     
 <p>
      <asp:Label ID="CreateAccountResults" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 </p>
```

I am not sure why this is not working?

Comment: Did you debug your code and check what value you are getting in variable `p`?

Comment: I think we'll need to know which Membership Provider you're using, like the built-in sql membership, for ex. It looks like you're not using the standard login control from the toolbox and I'm wondering why.

Answer (score 0):

You should "prepare" for an exception and read from its status property as to what was the result of user creation.

Proper usage from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership.createuser?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public void CreateUser_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  try
  {
    // Create new user.   
    MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(UsernameTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text);


    // If user created successfully, set password question and answer (if applicable) and 
    // redirect to login page. Otherwise return an error message.    
    if (Membership.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer)
    {
      newUser.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(PasswordTextbox.Text,
                                              PasswordQuestionTextbox.Text,
                                              PasswordAnswerTextbox.Text);
    }

    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
  }
  catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
  {
    Msg.Text = GetErrorMessage(e.StatusCode);
  }
  catch (HttpException e)
  {
    Msg.Text = e.Message;
  }
}

public string GetErrorMessage(MembershipCreateStatus status)
{
   switch (status)
   {
      case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
        return "Username already exists. Please enter a different user name.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
        return "A username for that email address already exists. Please enter a different email address.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
        return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
        return "The email address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
        return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
        return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
        return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
        return "The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
        return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

      default:
        return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but why is the version of the method @Ellen uses not working? It does not throw an exception according to the docs, and simply returns null if it doesn't work, with the status in the out parameter?

Comment: Might be because its passed with "out"? I might be misinterpreting this, but:
System.Enum is a reference type, but any specific enum type is a value type. In the same way, System.ValueType is a reference type, but all types inheriting from it (other than System.Enum) are value types.